# Combining metadata from multiple sources

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

In a SPA app using breeze, how would I go about combining metadata from multiple sources for related data so that I can use them in 1 manager on the client. For example, I might have the following

- Entity Framework Metadata from WebAPI controller (e.g. Account)
- Custom Metadata from DTOs (e.g. Invoices)
- Data from a third party service with metadata provided from client side metadata (e.g. Invoice transmission result)

In each case the data has related properties so I might want to be able to use Account.Transactions.TransmissionResults

**UPDATE**

I have tried several ways of getting this to work but to no avail. From Jay's answer, it is not possible at present to update the metadata from the server once it has been retrieved, so if and until that changes (see [breeze user voice issue](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4293820-give-the-developers-more-extensibility-on-the-meta)) I am left with one of the following approaches

1 Retrieve metadata from the server from Entity Framework and add metadata on the client to add extra entities. This worked to a degree but I could not add navigation properties from entity types added on the client to entity types retrieved from the server because I cannot add the foreign key association to the entity retrieved from the server, again back to the need to modifying metadata after it has been retrieved.

2 Write the complete metadata by hand, which will work but makes maintainability that much harder and seems wrong to be manually writing mostly the same code that the designer would write.

3 Generate most of the code from Entity Framework as described in the docs and then update it afterwards to add in the custom entities. Again similar issues than with option 2, it seems hacky.

Anyone else tried something similar? Is there something I am missing, which I could be, I've only started with breeze and js.

Thanks

Comment: It's a reasonable request and one we've been getting more frequently lately.  We are working now on a mechanism to allow you to extend the client side metadata.  No release date yet but we do hope to get it out within the next few months.

Comment: Thanks, that'll make breeze a great fit for this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A breeze EntityManager can have metadata from any number of DataService endpoints, and you can manually add metadata (new EntityTypes) on the client at any point.  The only current restriction is that once you have metadata from a specific service, you can't change it. ( We are considering reviewing the last restriction).

So the question is, what are you trying to do that you can't right now?

Comment: The issue I am having is that I would like to use Entity Framework for metadata and reading/writing for most of the tables and to use DTOs and named saves for a number of the more complex business objects. The entities from both sources are related. Ideally I would like to use a breeze manager that has metadata from both sources and that has navigation properties between the 2. It's adding the link between entities from different sources that has me stumped right now

Comment: I should add that we are using EF database first with an existing database.